# Access violation reading location (raw pointer variable)

Tags: c++

I tried this program but I got some issues, I used raw pointer to my variable name, so I had to deep copy the constructor, but I fell into an error! The problem comes from the name variable declared as pointer to a char. Here's my code:

```
class Player
{
protected:
    int xp;
    double health,xPos,yPos;
    char* name;
public:
    Player()                            
        :xp(0),health(100),name{nullptr},xPos(0),yPos(0){}
    Player(int xp, double health, double xPos, double yPos, char* n)    
        :name{nullptr}
    {
        this->xp = xp;
        this->health = health;
        this->xPos = xPos;
        this->yPos = yPos;
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        name = n;
    }
    Player(char* name)
        :xp(0), health(100), name{ nullptr }, xPos(0), yPos(0)
    {
        this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        this->name = name;
    }
    Player(const Player& p)         
    {
        xp = p.xp;
        health = p.health;
        xPos = p.xPos;
        yPos = p.yPos;
        name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
        name = p.name;
    }
    Player(Player&& p)                      
        :xp{p.xp}, health{p.health}, name{p.name}, xPos{p.xPos}, yPos{p.yPos}
    {
        p.name = nullptr;
        p.health = 0;
        p.xp = 0;
        p.xPos = 0;
        p.yPos = 0;
    }
    ~Player()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }

    Player& operator=(const Player& p)  
    {
        if (this == &p)
            return *this;
        delete[] name;
        name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
        name = p.name;
        xp = p.xp;
        health = p.health;
        xPos = p.xPos;
        yPos = p.yPos;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void Move_Player(double x, double y) = 0;
    virtual bool isDead(void) = 0;
    virtual void Display(void) = 0;
};
```

here's the cpp file for the class enemy:

```
Enemy::Enemy()
{
    xPos = 2.5;
    yPos = 2.5;
    health = 100;
    xp = 5;
}
Enemy::Enemy(int xp, double health, double xPos, double yPos, char* name)
{
    this->xp = xp;
    this->health = health;
    this->xPos = xPos;
    this->yPos = yPos;
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    this->name = name;
}
Enemy::Enemy(const Enemy& e)
{
    xp = e.xp;
    health = e.health;
    xPos = e.xPos;
    yPos = e.yPos;
    name = new char[strlen(e.name) + 1];
    name = e.name;
}
Enemy::Enemy(char* name)
{
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    this->name = name;
}
Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    delete[] name;
}
void Enemy::Move_Player(double x, double y)
{
    xPos += x;
    yPos += y;
}
bool Enemy::isDead(void)
{
    if (health == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
void Enemy::Display(void)
{
    std::cout << "The Position of the enemy is: x= " << xPos << ", y= " << yPos <<" and its health is: "<<health<< std::endl;
}
```

the problem is with my char variable!
has someone any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: `name = n;` does not copy string (it just assigns a pointer). Use `strcpy`, or better `std::string`.

Comment: You're making the same mistake with `name` - copying the pointer instead of the string -  in every constructor. (And you have memory leask.)

Comment: @DanielLangr thank you for this quick answer, but I want to manipulate pointer

Comment: @Idriss `name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; name = n;` — So, why do you allocate memory, if you overwrite the pointer in the very next step? You got a memory leak this way.

Comment: Copying a raw pointer in a copy constructor will cause undefined behaviour when two instances try to `delete[]` the same memory. Why not just use `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
```

directly followed by

```
name = n;
```

then that's similar to e.g.

```
int a;
a = 10;
a = 5;
```

and then wondering why `a` is no longer equal to `10`.

With the second assignment you make `name` point to the same location as  `n`, and the original location (the memory returned by `new[]`) is lost.

Because you have multiple pointers pointing to the same location, if you `delete[]` one of them then all other pointers will become invalid (since the memory they point to will no longer exist).

---

If I try to do it somewhat graphical, then you start out with `name == nullptr`:

```
+------+
| name | ---> null
+------+

+------+      +-----------+
|  n   | ---> | a name... |
+------+      +-----------+
```

Then you do

```
name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
```

and you have

```
+------+      +------------------------------+
| name | ---> | some uninitialized memory... |
+------+      +------------------------------+

+------+      +-----------+
|  n   | ---> | a name... |
+------+      +-----------+
```

And now you do the assignment

```
name = n;
```

which leads to the situation

```
+------+      +------------------------------+
| name | -\   | some uninitialized memory... |
+------+   \  +------------------------------+
            \
+------+     \    +-----------+
|  n   | -----+-> | a name... |
+------+          +-----------+
```

Both `name` and `n` are pointing to the same location, and you have no pointer pointing to the memory you just allocated.

From this situation, if you then do `delete[] name` you have the following situation:

```
+------+      +------------------------------+
| name | -\   | some uninitialized memory... |
+------+   \  +------------------------------+
            \
+------+     \
|  n   | -----+-> ???
+------+
```

The memory pointed to by both `name` and `n` is released, but the memory you allocated in the constructor still exists, but you can no longer access it.

---

Now for the solution: Instead of the assignment `name = n` you need to copy the memory pointed to by `n` into the memory pointed to by `name`:

```
strcpy(name, n);
```

An even better solution is to not use pointers at all, and instead use `std::string` for all your strings. Then you *can* use plain and simple assignment.

Comment: the problem is not there, it's before, it's in the execution of name=new char[..], I debug it to see where it throws the exception

Comment: @Idriss Possibly you've done this before, and then the pointer you pass to the constructor becomes invalid as one object have deleted the memory? Or if the memory pointed to by `n` isn't dynamically allocated, there could be something going wrong when you attempt to `delete[]` it? Without a proper [mcve] and some debugging effort it's going to be very hard to say anything more than "don't do what you're currently doing!".

Answer (score 0):

To add to Some programmer dude's answer, what you need to do instead is this

```
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
```

and the same for all the other place where you are copying `name`.

`strcpy` copies the characters being pointed to, your code copies the pointer itself.